# How to get Table Html except first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table and want to get HTML of that without first row of it.

I know that I can do this:

```
$('#mytable tr:first').remove();
var tableHtml = $('#mytable').html();
```

but in this way my table will change and first row of it will remove permanently

how can i do this without changing of my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way!

First, you need to clone the table element:

```
var clone = $("#mytable").clone();
```

Then, you remove the first row and get HTML:

```
console.log(clone.find("tr:first").remove().end().html());
//                find first row then remove |      |
//                                           |      +--------+
//                                      go back to parent    |
//                                                           |
//                                                       get HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not(:first-of-type)` to select `<tr>` tags except the first one.

```
var rows = $('#mytable tr:not(:first-of-type)');
```

Comment: it gives me array of rows,but i want entire html string(with table,thead,tbody,...)